# How to create section heading like this

Tags: graphics, sectioning

I need to create a heading style like this. Kindly help me to create the same. Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: You should take a  look at the `titlesec` package. Your section should be unnumbered?

Comment: yes. section number not needed

Comment: Please clarify a point : is it supposed to be the header corresponding to a section mark, or the section heading in the main text?

Comment: section heading in the main text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\myblackbox}[1]{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{#1}}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\color{white}\myblackbox}%
[{\raisebox{1ex}[0pt]{\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{0.8pt}}}]

\begin{document}

\section{Properties of the Series}

In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, 
Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven 
Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, 
excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places 
you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to  
find out all about them.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard. This code is not working.

Comment: What does ‘not working’ mean exactly?

Comment: \titleformat
                {\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\color{white}\myblackbox}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @JaiKumar: Sorry, it's my fault: I reorganised the preamble before posting, and did not notice that `\titleformat{...}`  was split in two, with the first part *before* loading `titlesec`, and the optional argument after.  Please try the fixed code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your timely help. Now it is working. Thank you.